# Dynamics 365 Portal - adding option to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-portals

I am currently working on the dynamics 365 Portal using JavaScript to fill in option sets populated by dynamics. Currently I have emptied the existing array and set the size of the display array to the new array.

Usually in this situation you would use push, add or concat to add on the array however I seem to be unable to use these methods.

Does anyone have any advice on how to add the options?
Below is an example of the switch statement I am currently using:

```
switch (region.toString()) {
  case "3546564": // value for the region
    {
      // Making the cleared array the same size as the new array
      countyPrvOptions.length = countyList.length;

      for (var j = 0; j < countyList.length; j++) {
        // attempting to push each option of the new array into the display array
        countyPrvOptions.push(countyList[j].toString());
      }

      break;
    }
}
```